# Rails Active Record Query with 3 tables with 1 having both information

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have an User, Payment, and PaymentRefund, Invoice tables

```
Voucher has_many Payments
Payment belongs_to User belongs_to Invoice
PaymentRefund has User and has Payment
Invoice has_many Payments
```

I have this query

```
User.joins(:payment).where('payments.status': 'settled', 'payments.invoice_id': @invoice.id)
```

What I want is this including User objects that do is not part of the PaymentRefund. Can someone help me with this active record query?

Currently getting this by

```
vouchers = Voucher.joins(:payment).where('payments.status': 'settled')

payment_refunds = PaymentRefunds.where(user_id: @user, invoice_id: invoice.id)
vouchers - payment_refunds
```

Comment: what you want is users which are not refunded and whose voucher is settled.

Comment: can you include table structure in your question

Comment: @jmoon90 PaymentRefund has User and has Payment. is it has many or has one association?

Comment: try this `User.joins(:payment_refunds).where(payment_refunds: { user_id: @user, invoice_id: @invoice.id}).joins(:payment).where('payments.status': 'settled', 'payments.invoice_id': @invoice.id).join(:vouchers)`

Comment: or `User.joins(:payment_refunds: payments: [:vouchers]).where(payment_refunds: { user_id: @user, invoice_id: @invoice.id }, payments: { status: 'settled', invoice_id: @invoice.id })`.

Comment: @jmoon90 i haven't tested because i don't have sample data.